# Sorting XML data based on Attribute Value

Tags: php, arrays, xml, sorting

Need help guys
Ive managed to find an easier XML feed to work with now and its perfect

The only problem is it doesnt order the results returned by date

here is the xml file

```
<event name="1m Maiden Stakes" eventid="5079164.20" date="20160105" time="1840" meeting="PORNICHET" venue="PORNICHET">
<bettype bet-start-date="20160105" bet-start-time="1840" ewreduction="5" ewplaceterms="3" eachway="1/5 Odds Place 1,2,3" suspended="false" name="Outright Betting" inrunning="0" bettypeid="25369679.20">
<bet jockey-silk="UqoAoo" name="Vision D'or" short-name="Vision D'" id="264074276.20" price="5/4" priceDecimal="2.25" priceUS="125.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="MqoAoo" name="Le Moulleau" short-name="Le Moulle" id="264074277.20" price="10/1" priceDecimal="11.00" priceUS="1000.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="TiqGii" name="Brancaio" short-name="Brancaio" id="264074278.20" price="10/1" priceDecimal="11.00" priceUS="1000.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="PqlAqq" name="Bracoeur" short-name="Bracoeur" id="264074279.20" price="16/1" priceDecimal="17.00" priceUS="1600.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="LoqGoo" name="Never Compromise" short-name="Never Com" id="264074280.20" price="12/1" priceDecimal="13.00" priceUS="1200.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="HrbAbr" name="Machistador" short-name="Machistad" id="264074281.20" price="9/1" priceDecimal="10.00" priceUS="900.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="UkkRkk" name="Royal Hawk" short-name="Royal Haw" id="264074282.20" price="8/1" priceDecimal="9.00" priceUS="800.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="AqqGoo" name="Normandy Kitten" short-name="Normandy" id="264074283.20" price="9/2" priceDecimal="5.50" priceUS="450.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="OqpAii" name="Tour" short-name="Tour" id="264074284.20" price="25/1" priceDecimal="26.00" priceUS="2500.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="UqhRhq" name="Beninio" short-name="Beninio" id="264074285.20" price="16/1" priceDecimal="17.00" priceUS="1600.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="OqoGoo" name="Just You And Me" short-name="Just You" id="264074286.20" price="33/1" priceDecimal="34.00" priceUS="3300.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
</bettype>
</event>
<event name="1m Stakes " eventid="5079167.20" date="20160105" time="1910" meeting="PORNICHET" venue="PORNICHET">
<bettype bet-start-date="20160105" bet-start-time="1910" ewreduction="5" ewplaceterms="3" eachway="1/5 Odds Place 1,2,3" suspended="false" name="Outright Betting" inrunning="0" bettypeid="25369682.20">
<bet name="Blue Kanto" short-name="Blue Kant" id="264074319.20" price="10/1" priceDecimal="11.00" priceUS="1000.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="ToqGoo" name="Francky Minuty" short-name="Francky M" id="264074320.20" price="16/1" priceDecimal="17.00" priceUS="1600.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="CmkAkk" name="Rizzichop" short-name="Rizzichop" id="264074321.20" price="12/1" priceDecimal="13.00" priceUS="1200.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="YblQlb" name="Colibri Cael" short-name="Colibri C" id="264074322.20" price="12/1" priceDecimal="13.00" priceUS="1200.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="CibGii" name="Ali Alexandra" short-name="Ali Alexa" id="264074323.20" price="12/1" priceDecimal="13.00" priceUS="1200.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet name="Nayfah" short-name="Nayfah" id="264074324.20" price="4/5" priceDecimal="1.80" priceUS="-80.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="RhmHmh" name="Elusive Dancer" short-name="Elusive D" id="264074326.20" price="4/1" priceDecimal="5.00" priceUS="400.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="GanAaa" name="Kersea" short-name="Kersea" id="264074327.20" price="20/1" priceDecimal="21.00" priceUS="2000.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="SlbGll" name="La Reussite" short-name="La Reussi" id="264074328.20" price="20/1" priceDecimal="21.00" priceUS="2000.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
<bet jockey-silk="UlqAlb" name="Dream Cat" short-name="Dream Cat" id="264074329.20" price="16/1" priceDecimal="17.00" priceUS="1600.00" active-price-types="SP,EP"/>
</bettype>
</event>
```

Here is my PHP code

```
$xmlData = 'http://xml.betfred.com/Horse-Racing-Daily.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlData);
$curdate = date('d/m/Y');
$i = 0;
    foreach ($xml->event as $event)
        if ($i < 5) {
        {
            //20160112
        $eventd = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},6,2);
        $eventm = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},4,2);
        $eventy = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},0,4);
        $eventdate = $eventd.'/'.$eventm.'/'.$eventy;
        $eventid = $event->attributes()->{'eventid'};
        $eventtime = $event->attributes()->{'time'};
        $eventname = $event->attributes()->{'name'};
        echo "<a href=\"event/".$eventname."/".$eventid."\">".$event->attributes()->venue.' - '.$eventtime.' - '.$eventname."</a><br />".$eventdate."<br />";
        $i++;} }
```

at the minute its only displaying the first 5 results which is fine, however i need to arrange and display the data by the $eventtime value which is the  $event->attributes()->{'time'}; value

Please help guys I'm so almost there after stressing so much over these xml feeds

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do in this case, if I don't have a way to change how the data is being output by the database, I would load it into PHP as an associative array and sort the keys.  Something like this:

```
<?php 

$xmlData = 'http://xml.betfred.com/Horse-Racing-Daily.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlData);
$curdate = date('d/m/Y');

$new_array = array();
$limit = 5;
$c = 0;
foreach ($xml->event as $event) {
    if ($limit == $c) {
        break;
    }
    $c++;
    $eventd = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},6,2);
    $eventm = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},4,2);
    $eventy = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},0,4);
    $eventt = $event->attributes()->{'time'};
    $new_array[$eventy.$eventm.$eventd.$eventt] = array(
        'eventd' => $eventd,
        'eventm' => $eventm,
        'eventy' => $eventy,
        'eventt' => $eventt,
        'eventdate' => $eventd.'/'.$eventm.'/'.$eventy,
        'eventid' => $event->attributes()->{'eventid'},
        'eventtime' => $event->attributes()->{'time'},
        'eventname' => $event->attributes()->{'name'},
        'venue' => $event->attributes()->venue,
    );
}

ksort($new_array);
foreach ($new_array as $event_time => $event_data) {
    echo "<a href=\"event/".$event_data['eventname']."/".$event_data['eventid']."\">".$event_data['venue'].' - '.$event_data['eventtime'].' - '.$event_data['eventname']."</a><br />".$event_data['eventdate']."<br />";
}
```

Of course this is NOT TESTED.

**EDIT** - Tested and it works now.

The point is that you load the array first with the information you need, sort by the key of the associative array and then print out what you want.  You could change the limit on either the full loaded list, or just the first 5 from the xml file.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks, its throwing up a syntax error in the $new_array line but I cant figure out whats wrong with it

Comment: still struggling, anyone able to shed some light on this please ??

Comment: jesus you must be really new because to fix that error (as I just edited the answer) was to take the greater than symbol out of the assignment.  Anyway, I just ran it with the simplexml code and it works now!  Just needed to take that part out.  I also remembered that ksort takes the array by reference so you don't need `$sorted_array`.  The problem is updated and it works.

Comment: Many thanks, have never really used arrays, but starting to get into them slowly

Comment: Well here's a really good example of using an associative array and sorting by it's key.  You can also sort by it's value etc...  Arrays is a data structure that is REALLY REALLY REALLY important when dealing with data.  I would recommend not dipping your toes in but to actually run and jump off a diving board into them.  Glad it worked for you and good luck!

Comment: Ive just tried and for some reason with the limit at 5 it doesnt show the first 5 entries will pick some randomly, if you set it to 10 itll show 6 but if you remove the limit it shows them all

Comment: Take out the limit in the first loop and implement it in the second loop, that way you process the full file and only spit out the first 5 sorted.  Fiddle with it til' you get the result you need.